# How to store the value of the 2nd to the last value to compare to the new value

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

I have this code

```
string[,] table = new string[104, 15];
int xIndex = -1;
int yIndex = 0;
string newPrevious = "placeholder";
//P = BLUE, B = RED, T = GREEN
string[] strData = {"P  ,B  ,P  ,P B,B  ,P  ,B  ,T  ,P  ,P  "};

//conditions
string[] scoreBoard = new string[]
{"P  ", "B  ", "T  ",
 "P B","B P" };
string OriginalData = "";


void Start(){
    StartCoroutine ("Win_Log");
}

IEnumerator Win_Log(){

    yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame ();

    for (int i = 0; i < strData.Length; i++) {
        OriginalData += strData [i];
        OriginalData += ",";
    }
    string[] newNewData = OriginalData.Split (',');
    string result = "";

    foreach (string newStrData in newNewData) {
        Debug.Log ("This is the data : " + newStrData);

        GameObject o = Instantiate (prefab_gameobject) as GameObject;
        o.transform.SetParent (pos_big_road);
        o.transform.localScale = Vector3.one;

        img = (RawImage)o.GetComponent<RawImage> ();

        //check the length so that it won't throw an exception
        if (newStrData.Length > 1) {
            //get only the first letter of the value P,B,T
            result = newStrData.Substring (0, 1);
        } 
        else {
            result = "";
        }

        #region BIG ROAD
        if(table.GetLength(0) < xIndex){
            break;
        }

        if (result.Equals (newPrevious) || result.Equals("T") && yIndex < table.GetLength (1)) {
            yIndex += 1;
            table [xIndex, yIndex] = result;
        }
        else if(newPrevious.Equals("T") && yIndex < table.GetLength (1)){
            yIndex += 1;
            table [xIndex, yIndex] = result;
        }
        else
        {
            xIndex += 1;
            yIndex = 0;
            table [xIndex, yIndex] = result;
        }
        newPrevious = result ;

        o.transform.localPosition = new Vector3 (xIndex * 93, yIndex * -93, 0f);
```

What my problem here is this

[image]

As you can see on the last column which is

> RED,GREEN,BLUE,BLUE

which is its value is

```
//P = BLUE, B = RED, T = GREEN
string[] strData = {"P  ,B  ,P  ,P B,B  ,P  ,B  ,T  ,P  ,P  "};
```

the `BLUE, BLUE` must be on the next row because its is not the equals to the `newPrevious` variable by which mean i was talking about the `RED` above the `GREEN` value . So you must be confused about this but the `GREEN` value is more like be disregarded what i mean by disregarded is like this

[image]

Now on the last column theres a value of

> BLUE, BLUE, GREEN, RED, RED

which its value is

```
//P = BLUE, B = RED, T = GREEN
string[] strData = {"P  ,B  ,P  ,P B,B  ,P  ,P  ,T  ,B  ,B  "};
```

As you can see in the image the `RED, RED` must be on the next row because it is not equal to the `newPrevious` variable by which mean i was talking about the `BLUE` above the `GREEN` value.

## NOW WHAT I WANT THAT I CAN'T ACHIEVE:

What i can't achieve here is to put the value of `newPrevious` to a variable in which it will store the value before the `GREEN` so that i can compare it with the new `newPrevious` value.

For example the picture above has the value

> RED, GREEN, BLUE, BLUE

i want to save the `RED` value so that i can compare it with the `BLUE` value so that i can increment it with the `xIndex` instead of `yIndex`

## EDIT

The first image expected output must be this

[image]

And the second image expected output must be like this

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take another variable "previous". Set it to the value of newPrevious as you are doing now and in the next iteration check if it has changed.

Replace this

```
newPrevious = result ;
```

With this

```
if(!result.Equals("T")) 
   newPrevious = result ;
```

Comment: the problem with this code is that all of of the `RED` and `BLUE` value is now all on X axis only . Now it doesn't follow my code on the `if else` statement

Comment: When you wish to change the row(update the y-axis), use the value of previous in the if statement

Comment: Sorry i don't quite understand i am very sorry.

Comment: Could you show me the expected output for the first image..ill be able to help you better then

Comment: I'll edit my question and show you the expected output

Comment: I Edited the question.

Comment: In that case don't set the newPrevious when its green. Use this in your original code,  if(!result.Equals("T")) newPrevious = result ;

Comment: Updated the answer!